# Как правильно завершить выполнение ожидаемого Task по условию CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, .net-core, task

Есть `.NET Core Hosted Service` (Background Worker) приложение, которое работает бесконечно, до тех пор, пока его не отключат.

Интерфейс стандартного .NET Core абстрактного класса `BackgroundService` предоставляет метод `Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)`. Он у меня реализован примерно так:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        _listener.Start(); // _listener инициализируется в конструкторе

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            var thread = new Thread(async () => await ProcessClientAsync(client, stoppingToken));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Unexpected error was occured");
    }
}
```

При завершении работы приложения этот `stoppingToken` становится `Cancelled`.
Проблема в том, что если во время ожидания `await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();` закрыть приложение, то оно упадет со следующей ошибкой:

> System.OperationCanceledException: 'The operation was canceled.'

Причем эта ошибка бросается за пределами метода `ExecuteAsync`. Как я понимаю, это из-за того, что текущий поток все еще ожидает завершения `await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();`, но оно не завершается.

**Вопрос:** Как обернуть вызов метода `await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();` таким образом, чтобы его ожидание завершилось по условию `stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested`? Чтобы, например, если `stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested == true`, то бросилось бы исключение определенного типа (например, `OperationCancelledException`)

Видел такую вот обертку, но не уверен в том, насколько это правильно:

```
public static async Task<T> WithWaitCancellation<T>(
    this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // The tasck completion source. 
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    // Register with the cancellation token.
    using (cancellationToken.Register(
            s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs))
        // If the task waited on is the cancellation token...
        if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task))
            throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);

    // Wait for one or the other to complete.
    return await task;
}
```

Comment: [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62611838/12888024) использования CTS. Еще есть `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` - бросит `OperationCancelledException`, если токен отменен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае - никак. Да, вы можете избавиться от исключения, но основная-то проблема заключается в том, что часть программы и не думает завершаться и её приходится прерывать по тайм-ауту.

В частном же случае с `TcpListener` его можно банально остановить:

```cs
try {
    using (stoppingToken.Register(_listener.Stop)) {
        while (true) {
            await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            // ...
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException ex) when (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Interrupted) {
    // ничего не делаем, это нормальная остановка
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // пишем в лог
}
```

Вообще, не надо забывать про метод `Register`, он так же полезен как и свойство `IsCancellationRequested`, если не полезнее.

PS если уж вы пишете асинхронный код - зачем вы создаёте потоки через Thread.Start? Этот ваш поток будет жить исключительно до первого же не-холостого оператора await!

PPS если уж вы пишите `BackgroundService` - после цикла стоило бы дождаться завершения всех порожденных задач.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115321/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-mayorov-----).